# How do I fix DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made a bot that deletes text messages in an image channel, but when I use it it's logs this error.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const users = ['853248522563485717'];
    if (message.channel.id === '841260660960395287') {
        if (users.includes(message.author.id)) return;
        if (message.attachments.size !== 0) return;
        message.member.send("You can't send text in 'images' channel")
         await message.delete();
    } else return;
});
```

(this is different from the other questions with the same topic)
how do I fix it?

Comment: you sure u aren't running multiple shells of the same bot? that way it may attempt to delete messages that were already deleted

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the problem, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: close the other shell running? it shouldn't be hard ;-;

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you are running multiple instances of the Discord bot. Check if you have multiple command lines open, if so, check if they are running the bot. Apart from that, if users spam, Discord API tends to get confused about which messages to delete, making it try to delete the same message more than 1 time. You can try adding an if statement checking if the message is undefined.

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (!message) return; // ADDED THIS LINE OF CODE
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const users = ["853248522563485717"];
  if (message.channel.id === "841260660960395287") {
    if (users.includes(message.author.id)) return;
    if (message.attachments.size !== 0) return;
    message.member.send("You can't send text in 'images' channel");
    await message.delete();
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: this now gives me a new error - 
(node:15092) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Comment: @Dawid Szarek, his issue is that he is using multiple `on message` events.

Comment: Ah yes, it is the case

Answer (score 0):

From your error above, you are seemingly using a `message event listener` for every command or function you want your bot to perform. The maximum for this is 11 (of the same type). This is not the correct way to do this.

### ***What is an event listener?***

```js
//the 'client.on' function is called every time a 'message' is sent

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  //do code
});
```

### ***How to fix this:***

Instead of using 1 event listener per command, use 1 for the whole client. You could solve this a multitude of ways, with [command handlers](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/) or such, however I will keep it simple.

This is the basic setup you should see in your `index.js` or `main.js` file:

```js
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// on message, run this
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message) return;
    console.log(`message sent in ${message.channel.name}. message content: ${message.content}`);
    //this event will fire every time a message is sent, for example.
});

// login to Discord with your app's token
client.login('your-token-goes-here');
```

So what do you do if you want to do multiple functions with your bot? (for example deleting text in an images only channel **and** logging messages to console)

Command handling. It is the only way. I linked an official Discord.js guide above, read through it and see what you can do. I would highly recommend trying this with an entirely different bot and clean index file, as it would be easier than trying to fit in code you dont understand between your already problematic code.